# can i get user name from Facebook api? , I need user name to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Hi I just use this api for getting user details but I can't get user name please help me

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture.type(large),groups" forKey:@"fields"]]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

     if (error==nil) {
     }else {

         NSLog(@"facebook erro : %@ ",error);
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permissions to access data which is not public.

[Check the blog here, it mentions how to request permission for private data.](http://hoangtran.me/ios/development/2016/08/20/use-graph-api-to-retrieve-facebook-user-information-in-ios/)

This is a snippet from the above blog

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email","username"] //not sure username is to be used or user_name.
let handler = loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, fromViewController: self, handler: handler)
```

After the user grants access to his private data. You will be able to retrieve the data.

Comment: FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_likes",@"user_groups",@"username",@"user_managed_groups"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if ([result.declinedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
        NSLog(@"declained permissions");
    } else {
        
        
    }
    
}];

Comment: if I use about code I got issue that is "invalid Scope: username"

Comment: Are you getting user id ?

Comment: No I use with FBSDKAccessToken.                                                                   if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture.type(large),groups" forKey:@"fields"]]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         
         if (error==nil) {
         }else {
             
             NSLog(@"facebook erro : %@ ",error);
         }
     }];
    
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Facebook iOS sdk get user name and email in swift 3 -

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
            print(fbDetails)
        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Not found")
        }
    })
```

Comment: You need to ask for permission to access private user data. The above snippet has no mention of username. The question is to retriever username.

Comment: yes I need that  thank you @MukulMore